# How to force javascript wait/block until deferred jobs done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, deferred

I have some code like:

```
var filteredData = [];

asyncFunc().done(function () {
    filteredData = blablabla...
});

return filteredData;
```

This is a project to deliver soon. I cannot change it to `callback` or `$.Deffered` due to the existing code/design.

Is it possible to force it to wait until `aysncFunc` have done its jobs and then return the real `filteredData` that I want?

**EDIT:**

@MerynStol you're right. Async was sent to last of the `job queue`(I forgot the term), which is after `while` and `return`. So when `while` ends, `return` execute immediately.

Should I keep on this or try to bargain more time for a re-structure?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible - it would require the restructure that you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Is it jquery code? Can you wrap it in `$.when(asyncFunc()).done( callback )` call?

Comment: @Baldrs I can not use callback or deferred here. And that's why it's so annoying. :(

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree with you. I raised this issue just because I've not found someone confirming that it's impossible after Google. Maybe some dark magic would happen on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Either ask for more time for restructure, leave out this particular feature, or see if you can implement this part of the code without indexeddb and/or websql after which you can probably get it all synchronous with sync xmlhttprequest. localStorage is synchronous, so maybe store the critical data also there.

Comment: It's quite normal to refactor code several times during the course of a project. This one doesn't sound particularly major and shouldn't take too long if the code is already organised into functions. Back up everything then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the `Function` prototype:

```
Function.prototype.and = Function.prototype.and || function(fn){
    this();
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments), arg;
    while (args.length) {
        arg = args.shift();
        if (arg instanceof Function) {
            arg();
        }
    }
}
```

and use it with a [comma operator](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/) like this:

```
var filteredData = [];
return (asyncFunc.and( function () {
    filteredData = /* do stuff */
} ), filteredData);
```

Or if method `done` works as expected just use:

```
var filteredData = [];
return (asyncFunc().done(function () {
    filteredData = /*blablabla...*/
 }), filteredData);
```

Comment: This will just run `asyncFunc` and call the anonymous function directly afterwards. Rather pointless.

Comment: Well, the question was: *Is it possible to force it to wait until `aysncFunc` have done its jobs and then return the real `filteredData` that I want?*, wasn't it?

Comment: No he wants to wait with returning "until deferred jobs are done", - impossible.